# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^3a_nx^{2n}.$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R$. Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^3a_nx^{2n}.$

$\underline{Attempt}$

Let
$y=x^2$,$$
f(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^3a_ny^{n}
$$

Then radius of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^3a_nx^{2n}$

$$R^\prime=\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg|\frac{n^3a_n}{(n+1)^3a_{n+1}}\bigg|=R$$
thus radius $|y|<R$ $\iff$ $|x^2|<R \iff |x|<\sqrt{R}$

radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^3a_nx^{2n}$ is  $|x|<\sqrt{R}.$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Mathematically it is correct, but there are minor issues with the phrasing. For example "radius of convergence [...] is $|x|<\sqrt R$". The raidius of convergence is $\sqrt R$ and not $|x|<\sqrt R$.

Comment: @Gary Got it Thank you very much..